# how to reload page until a button appears using capybara and ruby

Tags: ruby, capybara

I want to click a button after an action and button does not appear until and unless I reload the page. And some times it takes some time to appear the button and I have to reload page for more than once. I don't want to put static delays. So is there a way to achieve following using capybara and ruby:

```
  do
    page.evaluate_script("window.location.reload()")
  until a button appears
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Mesut's code should work fine, I would re-write it as:

```
Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_max_wait_time) do
  loop do
    page.evaluate_script("window.location.reload()")
    break if page.has_selector?(...)
  end
end
```

This will make sure to fail if it will have to wait more than timeout defined in Capybara settings. It can be useful when for example specs are running on the CI server.

Be aware that it can still lead to unexpected behaviors in some drivers, because it can interrupt while some scripts are evaluating.

Comment: @waqas `page.has_selector(...) ` should be `page.has_selector?(...) ` otherway it won't work

Comment: @MesutGüneş Thanks. Upvoted and fixed in the code snippet.

Comment: Since `page.has_selector?` will already wait up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time for the element to appear this will never actually retry because the Timeout will trigger before the first attempt ends if the element doesn't appear

Comment: Per the [Capybara documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FSession:execute_script), you should use `execute_script` instead of `evaluate_script` here, since you aren't checking the value of the result.

Answer (score 0):

reoload until `page.has_selector?` returns true, check this:

```
while true 
  page.evaluate_script 'window.location.reload()'
  if page.has_selector?("css_selector")
    break
  end
end
```